# While I am filling combobox with observable collection from wcf service i am getting following Exception

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, combobox

While i am trying to fill combobox with observable collection which is consumed from wcf service i am getting following exception.Can anyone please help me

> Cannot create instance of 'MainWindow' defined in assembly
>   'SchoolManagementSystem, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'. Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation.  Error in markup file 'MainWindow.xaml' Line 1 Position 9.

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
            ObservableCollection<ClassDO> objClasslist = new ObservableCollection<ClassDO>(ClassList.GetClassList());
           // cmbclass.ItemsSource = objClasslist;
           // cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "ClassID";
            //cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "CLassName";
        } }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Window x:Class="SchoolManagementSystem.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="549" Width="668" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid Height="550" Width="600" Background="Beige" >

        <!--TextBlock Heading -->
        <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,0" Name="TextBlockHeading" Text="Registration: " VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" FontSize="17" >
        </TextBlock>

        <!--Button and styling of login-->
        <Button Margin="451,5,12,288" Content="LOGIN" Cursor="Hand" >
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <TextBlock TextDecorations="underline">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    </TextBlock>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
        <!--End of buttonstyling and link button-->

        <Grid Margin="31,0,29,23" Background="White"  VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="294"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,0,0,0" x:Name="errormessage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="247" OpacityMask="Crimson"
                       Foreground="#FFE5572C"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,20,0,0" Name="TextBlockStudentCode" Text="StudentCode" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,50,0,0" Name="TextBlockfullname" Text="FullName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,80,0,0" Name="TextBlockFatherName" Text="FatherName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,110,0,0" Name="TextBlockAddress" Text="Address" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,140,0,0" Name="TextBlockMobNo" Text="Mobile No" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,170,0,0" Name="TextBlockEmail" Text="Email" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,200,0,0" Name="TextBlockClass" Text="Class" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,230,0,0" Name="TextBlockSection" Text="Section" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110"></TextBlock>

            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,20,0,0"   Name="TextBoxStudentCode" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,50,0,0"  Name="TextBoxFullname" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,80,0,0" Name="TextBoxFatherName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,110,0,0" Name="TextBoxAddress" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,140,0,2" Name="TextBoxMobNo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,170,0,2" Name="TextBoxEmail" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cmbclass" ItemsSource="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" DisplayMemberPath="ClassName" SelectedValuePath="ClassID"/>

            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,230,0,2" Name="TextBoxSection" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="222"></TextBox>

            <Button Content="Submit" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,264,0,0" Name="Submit" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" Click="Submit_Click" />
            <Button Content="Reset" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="259,264,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"  />
            <Button Content="Cancel" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,264,60,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70"  />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Any Help Appreciated

Comment: Post inner exception here. And where have you placed this code?

Comment: In MyWindow.xaml.cs file below the Intializecomponent();

Comment: Error in markup file 'MainWindow.xaml' Line 1 Position 9. It would help if you posted the code...

Comment: Post complete XAML code here and like I mentioned above check for inner exception for exact cause.

Comment: Is this method `ClassList.GetClassList()` returning `IEnumerable<ClassDO>'?

Comment: ClassList.GetClassList() returning observable collection

Comment: So why are you creating new ObservableCollection out if it. Simply use that.

Comment: i am using like this also i am getting same exception                      ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client()Cmbclass.DataContext = ClassList.GetClassList();
          Cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "ClassID";
          Cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "CLassName";

Comment: I should repeat then you gotta add more details like inner exception before anyone can help you with it. Otherwise it will be more of guess work only.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make this more debuggable, move the lines out of the constructor and into the `Window_Loaded` handler (its in the xaml, but you didn't include it in the .cs).

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client ClassList = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
ObservableCollection<ClassDO> objClasslist = new ObservableCollection<ClassDO> ClassList.GetClassList()); //<-- Does this line even compile?
// cmbclass.ItemsSource = objClasslist;
// cmbclass.DisplayMemberPath = "ClassID";
//cmbclass.SelectedValuePath = "CLassName";
```

Your binding won't pick them up unless you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but you can always just get them working and move them back to the constructor later (or even better refactor to a method and call from loaded or constructor as necessary).